# MonetDB queries blocking MySQL writes

Tags: mysql, monetdb

When I run a large query in MonetDB, it appears to block writes to a MySQL database on the same server.  For example, when I run a simple insert without running a query on monetdb, I get immediate results:

`mysql> insert into test values (100);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)`

But when I am running a query on monetdb concurrently, the same mysql query takes much longer:

`mysql> insert into test values (100);
Query OK, 1 row affected (42.30 sec)`

It's not the actual disk speed, since a little dd test shows > 8 MB/s write speed of a random file whether monetdb has a query running or not. If anyone has any ideas about where to look next it would be very helpful.

I am running RHEL 5.9 and the following db versions:

Monetdb version
MonetDB Database Server Toolkit v1.1 (Oct2014-SP2)

MySQL version
mysql  Ver 14.12 Distrib 5.0.95, for redhat-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.1

Comment: What is your monetdb query?

Comment: Any query seems to do it. As an example: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM testtable WHERE testnullcol IS NULL AND rowid >= 12000000 AND rowid < 13000000;` But just about any query on the table 'testtable' will work. It has almost 1 billion rows.

Comment: How many CPU cores does your machine have?

Comment: Yes I was concerned about the cpu too but I have 8 cores, and I `set nthreads=4` for the database. I even reniced the monetdbd process to 10 just in case.

Comment: Its likely that there is simply IO contention and that MySQL's disk accesses have to wait a bit.